# Zoom Effect using css but the size of the div should be fixed

Tags: html, css

Edit: What if i don't know the width size ?

[js fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3f95gtk2/)

Please go to the above link. I want that zoom effect to take place without the div zooming on. Only the image should zoom inside the div.`I don't know where i am going wrong. Can someone help ?

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height: 100px !important;

}

.img-container img{
  height: 100px;  
  -moz-transition:all .8s;-webkit-transition:all .8s;transition:all .8s
}
.img-container:hover img{
  max-width:100%
  -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  transform: scale(1.4);  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="http://www.macforensicslab.com/images/icon_GoogleSearch.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="http://www.macforensicslab.com/images/icon_GoogleSearch.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="http://www.macforensicslab.com/images/icon_GoogleSearch.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="http://www.macforensicslab.com/images/icon_GoogleSearch.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would only need to set the width for the img-container for it to be able to "count" where to apply the `overflow:hidden;`from.

**EDIT based on comment:**

You can apply the zoom effect only on the first element like this:

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height: 100px !important;
  width: 100px;
}

.img-container img{
  height: 100px;  
  -moz-transition:all .8s;-webkit-transition:all .8s;transition:all .8s
}
.col-sm-4:first-child .img-container:hover img{
  max-width:100%
  -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  transform: scale(1.4);  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/eee/000"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/eee/000"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/eee/000"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/eee/000"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if i want the transition to apply for first image and not otherimages ?

Comment: You need to use the first-child css selector like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tvru7kme/2/

Comment: is there any other way ?

Comment: Well of course you can add a class to the first container for example `<div class="img-container hover">` on the element and then use css `.img-container.hover:hover img{ max-width:100% -moz-transform: scale(1.4); -webkit-transform: scale(1.4); transform: scale(1.4);  }

Comment: I have 3 images on top of the background image for a div. When i wrote the above the code. The 3 images on the top are also zooming in which is not what i need. Let me know if there is a way i could sort it out

The main div is in a loop. As there are elements coming from the server, this whole thing is repeated.

Comment: You should update your question or open a new one with code and description of what you want. This will turn out to a chat conversation if the continue.

Comment: Got it. I have added a class to those 3 images and set the transform property to none !important. Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok good that you got it resolved! Glad if I could provide some help :)

Answer (score 2):

The width of your image is 100px so give the container a fixed `width:100px;`

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height: 100px !important;
  width: 100px;
  
}

.img-container img{
  height: 100px;  
  -moz-transition:all .8s;-webkit-transition:all .8s;transition:all .8s
}
.img-container:hover img{
  max-width:100%
  -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  transform: scale(1.4);  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="http://www.macforensicslab.com/images/icon_GoogleSearch.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What if i want the transition to apply for first image and not otherimages ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in two ways:

You can use css float property:

```
.img-container {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin:0;
padding:0;
height: 100px !important;
 float:left;
}
```

Or you can also set the `width` for the container.

Comment: What if i want the transition to apply for first image and not otherimages ?

Comment: use the [css nth child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)